# ORTools task allocation optimization with duration

Tags: optimization, or-tools, cp-sat

I am using or-tools solution like https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/task_allocation_sat.py to allocate tasks to time slots where each task has periodicity and each time slot has capacity (how much tasks in max could be placed inside the time slot). Now I want to replace capacity constraint with constraint based on task duration, where each task has duration and each slot has max duration, so each time slot could has only as much tasks as its under the max duration limit. But I can't understand how to build constraint which is saying "Check sum of durations of tasks in a slot and it should be less than max_slot_duration".

```py
def main():
    available = [
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    ]

    periodicity = [
        2, 2, 1, 1, 3
    ]

    capacity = 3

    max_slot_duration = 124

    task_durations = [
        15, 20, 30, 50, 10
    ]

    ntasks = len(available)
    nslots = len(available[0])

    all_tasks = range(ntasks)
    all_slots = range(nslots)

    model = cp_model.CpModel()
    assign = {}
    for task in all_tasks:
        for slot in all_slots:
            assign[(task, slot)] = model.NewBoolVar('x[%i][%i]' % (task, slot))
    count = model.NewIntVar(0, nslots, 'count')
    slot_used = [model.NewBoolVar('slot_used[%i]' % s) for s in all_slots]

    for task in all_tasks:
        model.Add(
            sum(assign[(task, slot)] for slot in all_slots if available[task][slot] == 1) == periodicity[task])

    for slot in all_slots:
        model.Add(
            sum(assign[(task, slot)] for task in all_tasks
                if available[task][slot] == 1) <= capacity)
        for task in all_tasks:
            if available[task][slot] == 1:
                model.AddImplication(slot_used[slot].Not(),
                                     assign[(task, slot)].Not())
            else:
                model.Add(assign[(task, slot)] == 0)

    model.Add(count == sum(slot_used))

    model.Minimize(count)

    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
    solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 6
    solution_printer = TaskAssigningSolutionPrinter(all_tasks, all_slots, assign)
    status = solver.Solve(model, solution_printer)
    print(solution_printer.get_solution())
```

And solution printer

```py
class TaskAssigningSolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    def __init__(self, tasks, slots, assign):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.__tasks = tasks
        self.__slots = slots
        self.__assign = assign
        self.__solutions = {}
        self.__solution_count = 0

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        self.__solutions[self.__solution_count] = {}
        for slot in self.__slots:
            self.__solutions[self.__solution_count][slot] = []
            for task in self.__tasks:
                if self.Value(self.__assign[(task, slot)]) == 1:
                    self.__solutions[self.__solution_count][slot].append(task)
        self.__solution_count += 1

    def get_solution(self):
        return self.__solutions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Stradivari (Xiang) user of the or-tools discord channel solution was found.
We need just the sum constraint here.

```py
for slot in all_slots:
  model.Add(sum(assign[(task, slot)] * task_durations[task] for task in all_tasks if
                      available[task][slot] == 1) <= max_slot_duration * workers[slot])
```